# Format Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to format this:

```
/Date(1292962456255)/
```

as regular looking date in JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: What kind of a date is this? A timestamp?

Comment: Comes back to Json like this from a c3 Datetime object

Comment: what exactly is the expected output of this date?

Comment: I really don't know. For some reason passing a c# datetime through json to the view comes back like this after I perform a .toString() on it

Comment: @John -- maybe? i really dont know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I call an "Microsoft Date" and the following function will convert the encoded date to a javascript date time

```
            var msDateToJSDate = function(msDate) {
                var dtE = /^\/Date\((-?[0-9]+)\)\/$/.exec(msDate);
                if (dtE) {
                    var dt = new Date(parseInt(dtE[1], 10));
                    return dt;
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: This isn't valid JavaScript, there should be a = instead of a : on the first line -- and what's with the `return msEncodedDate`? If the string doesn't match the pattern, return the function itself? That doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @Theo your right about the equal.  but your second observation is wrong.  The function will return the a JS date if the string matches the regex.  otherwise return back the original value passed in. Clearly you could modify this to return an error code or null.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread and took the argument name for the function name. It's still a strange thing to do, I would be very surprised to get a string back when I expect a date. Returning null or raising an exception would be much more appropriate.

Comment: @Theo I would hope that C# is not passing invalid dates through JSON

Comment: You can never trust that what you get will always be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)! It's "A lightweight javascript date library for parsing, manipulating, and formatting dates". It is a really powerful little library.

Here's an example...

```
var today = moment(new Date());
today.format("MMMM D, YYYY h:m A");        // outputs "April 11, 2012 2:32 PM"

// in one line...
moment().format("MMMM D, YYYY h:m A");     // outputs "April 11, 2012 2:32 PM"
```

Here's another example...

```
var a = moment([2012, 2, 12, 15, 25, 50, 125]);
a.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Monday, March 12th 2012, 3:25:50 pm"
a.format("ddd, hA");                       // "Mon, 3PM"
a.format("D/M/YYYY");                      // "12/3/2012"
```

---

Also, its worth mentioning to checkout [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). I think the two libraries complement each other.

Answer (score 1):

The number is a timestamp with millisecond resolution. This number can be passed to JavaScript's `Date` class' constructor. All that is needed is some code to extract it from the string:

```
var dateString = "/Date(1292962456255)/";
var matches = dateString.match(/^\/Date\((\d+)\)\/$/);
var date = new Date(parseInt(matches[1], 10));
```

The regexp on the second line gets a bit messy since the string contains /, ( and ) at precisely the positions that they are needed in the regexp (are you sure what you have is strings that look like that, and not a description of a pattern that would extract them?).

Another way of doing it is to use `eval`:

```
var dateString = "/Date(1292962456255)/";
var date = eval("new " + dateString.substring(1, dateString.length - 1));
```

but that may open up for an XSS attack, so I don't recommend it.

Comment: Dont forget the radix on parseInt

Comment: Radix is not needed since it defaults to base 10.

Comment: that is not actually correct.  Radix does not default to base 10.  "If no radix argument is provided or if it is assigned a value of 0, the function tries to determine the base. If the string starts with a 1-9, it will be parsed as base 10. If the string starts with 0x or 0X it will be parsed as a hexidecimal number. If the string starts with a 0 it will be parsed as an octal number. (Note that just because a number starts with a zero, it does not mean that it is really octal.) "

Answer (score -2):

I think this a `microtime`. Similar to [PHP's microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) function. Or in `new Date().getTime()` in JavaScript.

```
// PHP
$ php -r "var_dump(microtime(true));"
float(1292963152.1249)

// JavaScript
new Date().getTime()
1292963411830
```

Comment: He asked for code that would format the date in the string, not what it was.