# using jquery to return dates

Tags: jquery

I am making a JQuery call to a web method and returning JSON, but I have a problem when I try to return dates, they come back in the format /Date(1298073600000)/.  Can anybody help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/CDServices.asmx/GetWeekEndingDates",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function(msg) {

            alert(msg.d.LastWeekEndingDate);

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If `msg.d.LastWeekEndingDate` contains `/Date(1298073600000)/`, you should apply a little regex to strip the timestamp:

```
var mydate = new Date(+msg.d.LastWeekEndingDate.match(/\/Date\((\w+)\)\//)[1]);
```

The regex returns a string literal which needs to get converted into a Number. I used the `+` infront of the expression to do that. Outcome is:

```
console.log(mydate);   // === Sat Feb 19 2011 01:00:00 GMT+0100 {}
```

**Update**:

The `Date object` exposes several methods to you. For instance:

```
console.log([mydate.getDate(), mydate.getMonth()+1, mydate.getFullYear()].join('/'));
```

would return `19/2/2011`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/CDServices.asmx/GetWeekEndingDates",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function(msg) {
            var aDate = new Date(msg.d.LastWeekEndingDate);
            var month = aDate.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = aDate.getDate();
            var year = aDate.getFullYear();
            var usethis = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, When 19/02/2011 00:00:00 is returned, this just gives me Nan/Nan/Nan

Comment: if you use 
alert(msg.d.LastWeekEndingDate);
and see 1298073600000. So my code works fine.

Comment: I have removed the timestamp, but strangely a msg.d.LastWeekEndingDate of 19/2/2011, when your code is applied to it gives a 'usethis' value of 2/7/2012..?

Comment: what's the value of msg.d.LastWeekEndingDate for "19/2/2011". And also check aDate.toString() value

Answer (score 0):

var dtE = /^/Date((-?[0-9]+))/$/.exec(msg.d.LastWeekEndingDate);
if (dtE) {
   var dt = new Date(parseInt(dtE[1], 10));
   alert(dt);
}

In reference to [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503504/format-date-in-javascript), this needs to be modified as your requirements.