# How should I instantiate this date in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format Date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503504/format-date-in-javascript)

I have this date:

```
var newDate = "/Date(1333609200000)/";
```

And what I need to do to it is:

```
var myDate = new Date(1333609200000);
```

I thought about just trimming off `"/Date()/"` and then getting just the number inside but I wasn't sure if that would be best here. Should I just simply regex the number out of that? Is there a better approach?

Notes: The date is being created by c#'s `JavascriptSerializer` and comes in the format `newDate` above. It cannot be changed in c# due to constraints.

Comment: How about `new Date(+newDate.replace(/\D/g, ""))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var newDate = "/Date(1333609200000)/";

 newDate= new Date(parseInt(newDate.match(/\d/g).join("")));
```

Comment: You'd better use `parseInt` with base argument.

Comment: @VisioN: Strictly speaking, not necessary here :) Dates don't start with `0x` nor with `0`.

Comment: @pimvdb True, just as a good practice :)